# named concrete interface inheriting from Function in java 8

Tags: java, inheritance, types, java-8, alias

I have a lot of places where I have a `Function<Foo,Foo>`.  I'd essentially like to alias this to `FooTransformer`. My first attempt was.

```
interface FooTransformer extends Function<Foo,Foo>{}
```

This ended up with complaints from the type types system when I tried composing `FooTransformer`

```
class Foo {}

interface FooTransformer extends Function<Foo,Foo> {}


public void TestFoo(){
    //two differently named identity transforms
    FooTransformer t1 = foo -> foo;
    FooTransformer t2 = foo -> foo;

    FooTransformer t3 = t1.andThen(t2);
}
```

This fails with

> Error:(93, 39) java: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) V exist so that java.util.function.Function conforms to org.broadinstitute.hellbender.tools.walkers.bqsr.ReadTransformerTest.FooTransformer

by modifying `FooTransformer` to overload `andThen` my code compiles and runs.

```
interface FooTransformer extends Function<Foo,Foo> {
    default FooTransformer andThen(FooTransformer after){
        return Function.super.andThen(after)::apply;
    }
}
```

I now get this warning though (using javac 1.8.0_25 with --Xlint:all)

> warning: [overloads] andThen(FooTransformer) in FooTransformer is
>   potentially ambiguous with andThen(Function) in
>   Function
>          default FooTransformer andThen(FooTransformer after){
>                                ^
>    where V,R,T are type-variables:
>      V extends Object declared in method andThen(Functionextends V>)
>      R extends Object declared in interface Function
>      T extends Object declared in interface Function

What a I really want is a type alias for `Function<Foo,Foo>` and this is a the closest I've been able to get.  Is there a better way to accomplish this without warnings?

Answer (score 3):

I don’t know which compiler you used, therefore I can’t test whether my proposed solution will solve your warning. The reason you get the warning is because your `andThen` method is very similar to the inherited method `Function.andThen` but does not override it. One possible solution could be to explicitly override the method `Function.andThen` as well:

```
interface FooTransformer extends Function<Foo,Foo> {

    @Override
    public default <V> Function<Foo, V> andThen(Function<? super Foo, ? extends V> after) {
        return Function.super.andThen(after);
    }
    default FooTransformer andThen(FooTransformer after){
        Objects.requireNonNull(after);
        return foo -> after.apply(apply(foo));
    }
}
```

Then it should be clear that you know that your `andThen` doesn’t override the method as the other does. However, as said, I can’t test whether this lets the warning disappear.

There is another aspect that this warning might try to address. If you have overloaded methods with `interface` parameter types, it creates a potential ambiguity for the case someone tries to call either method with a concrete type implementing *both* `interface`s. This doesn’t apply here as one parameter type is a subtype of the other, so it’s never ambiguous, but it seems that `javac` isn’t smart enough to recognize this. So you may enter a discussion with the `javac` developers about this, hoping for a future version not issuing the warning, however, adding `@SuppressWarnings("overloads")` at the method is the easier solution…

---

Note that I changed the implementation to not wrap the result of `Function.super.andThen` into a `FooTransformer`. While method references are a good way to translate arbitrary interface instances to another interface, I think that the overhead of wrapping a function into another function should be avoided when the actual implementation is known and as simple as in this case.

---

Note that you may consider letting your `FooTransformer` extend [`UnaryOperator<Foo>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/UnaryOperator.html), which is a sub-interface of `Function<Foo,Foo>`. So everything works as before but you gain the option to use instances of your `FooTransformer` with [`List.replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) or [`Stream.iterate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate-T-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) or [`AtomicReference.updateAndGet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html#updateAndGet-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-)…

Comment: I'm using javac 1.8.0_25.  I tried adding the explicit override function, but it just changes the warning to be that it's ambiguous with the definition in FooTransformer now.  Interesting point about performance.  I'll definitely consider that.  Also, thank you for pointing out the UnaryOperator.  That's definitely the correct class for me to be inheriting from in this situation. I hadn't known about it.

Comment: I should add that this warning only shows up with --Xlint:all.